# Binding custom vertex attributes for use in shaders

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glkit

I am writing a shader that does different things depending on a specific value tied to the vertex. Below is the struct that stores my vertex information:

```
typedef struct
{
    GLKVector3 position;
    GLKVector3 normal;
    GLKVector2 texCoords0;
    GLKVector4 originalColor;
    GLushort isEmissive;
    GLushort colorIndex;
} Vertex;
```

The important variable is `isEmissive`. I want to process different lighting/color effects in my fragment shader depending on this variable - it's essentially a BOOL (1 or 0). Since it's tied to my vertex information, I thought I could set an `attribute` property in my vertex shader but that doesn't seem to be the case. Is there a way to add/bind custom attributes for my vertex information to the vertex shader? All of the attributes I use in my vertex shader right now are standard - GLKVertexAttribPosition, GLKVertexAttribNormal, GLKVertexAttribColor, GLKVertexAttribTexCoord0 - or use NS_ENUMs from GLKit. Is there something I need to do to bind my own attributes to use in the vertex shader? I've tried binding `isEmissive` but it's always 0 in my shader. I want it to reflect the value when the vertex is created. I feel like I need to bind this data to the buffer so the vertex information on the GPU has access to this data.

UPDATE - I added the code below per the comment below. I setup the pointer into the vertex array object specifying where the data is I need. It's a single float value - 0 or 1.

```
    // emissive bool
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIB_EMISSIVE);
    glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIB_EMISSIVE, 1, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (GLbyte *)NULL + offsetof(Vertex, isEmissive));
```

Then in my shader program I added the following to bind the attribute:

```
    glBindAttribLocation(_program, ATTRIB_EMISSIVE, "isEmissive");
```

Finally, as a test to see if the value works I have the following in my shader:

```
// calculate new color based on time
if (isEmissive > 0.5) {
    colorVarying = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
} else {
    colorVarying = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

isEmissive is always 0. I've explicitly set it to 1 to verify that I'm not actually getting the right value. Is there an additional step I'm missing?

Comment: You need to use glVertexAttribPointer when configuration your Vertex Array Object to tell OpenGL about the attribute in your vertex data. Then you need to use glBindAttribLocation when configuring the program so OpenGL knows what vertex attribute to put in your attribute variable in the shader. I assume GLKit does this for you for the default types...

Comment: I updated my code above. I believe I've taken care of what you suggested but still not working. Do you see anything?

Comment: I fixed it. When setting the type parameter for glVertexAttribPointer I initially had GL_FLOAT, but the correct type is GL_SHORT. All is well. Thanks for help @heinrichj

Comment: Why are you using a `GLushort` for this property in the first place? Is it for alignment? Your data structure is the size of 13 floats, that is not alignment friendly to begin with. `position` should ideally begin on a 16-byte boundary if you pack this structure into an array.

Comment: I don't know. All I want is the smallest possible data type to store a value equivalent to a bool - 0 or 1. What data type should I use for this?

Comment: @kschins: `GLubyte`, that can represent 0-255 (8-bit) whereas `GLushort` is 0-65535 (16-bit).